# Need to store multiple values seperated by comma(,) in single column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm developing a website Which contains profile of n no of peoples.
Here what the user will do is, he/she want to log in to view the peoples details.Only register user have the rights to view the details and he can view n no peoples details on one time login.
when ever the user click on the each profile its id should store in database.

In a database i have field called profileid.
1st time when user click on the profile means its id is getting stored in profileid.

What i want is when the same user click another profile id ,then it should store in same field with previous one with comma(,).

Eg:

profieid
20
20,15
20,15,10.

Likewise it should store..

Here is my update query

```
string Name = (string)(Session["Name"]);
        string time = (string)(Session["Time"]);
        string sql = ("UPDATE  History set RegID_UserProfile='" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + "' WHERE UserName='" + Name + "' and LoginTime='" + time + "'");
        SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        int temp = cmd7.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            //aa
        }
        con.Close();
```

Anyone have the idea to achieve this???

Comment: First thing to change: stop using string concatenation in your SQL. Use parameterized SQL instead. Fix that before you do *anything* else. See http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: DO NOT do this. store these values in a separate table and use a Foreign Key to link them together.

Comment: Yeah, what Jon and Randy said...
I built something like that 15 years ago when I was young and stupid.  Please learn from our mistakes.  :)

Comment: No, you **want** to store comma separated values. You don't **need** to, and in fact, as Randy suggests, it would be a far better design to store this data in a separate table. SQL has two data types that are *designed* for holding multiple values. `varchar` (or any of its variants) isn't one. They're `xml` (but only use that if your data is naturally "XMLish") and tables.

Comment: Thanks for all ....i implemented the way Randy Suggested it sounds good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the following line in your code would help you achieve what you want:

```
string sql = ("UPDATE  History set RegID_UserProfile=RegID_UserProfile + ',' + '" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + "' WHERE UserName='" + Name + "' and LoginTime='" + time + "'");
```

But now a piece of advice, **what you are doing and the way you are doing is immencely outdated, haveing too many flaws and secutiry vulnerabilities.** You should look for new methods of db access.

Hope this helps.